# Disable PropertySortOrder in SCSS-Lint in Atom

Tags: sass, atom-editor, lint, scss-lint

I would like to disable PropertySortOrder(https://github.com/brigade/scss-lint/tree/master/lib/scss_lint/linter#propertysortorder) in SCSS-Lint in Atom, though the documentation doesn't really specify how to do this.

It appears that I can disable this by file(https://github.com/brigade/scss-lint/tree/master/lib/scss_lint/linter#disablelinterreason), but I would quite like to set it my configuration.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a `.scss-lint.yml` file and add it to your home folder *(or project folder, in case you want project-specific linting)*, then add your global settings there - in your case it should be

`linters:
  PropertySortOrder:
    enabled: false`

Atom's css linter is using the scss-lint gem, so it will pick up the default settings from the configuration file by default if no project-specific settings are specified.